# awk repetition {n} is not working

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I am trying to print the lines using the repetition symbol {n} but it is not working. 
For. e.g. I want to print all lines whose length is 4 char long

```
 awk '/^.{4}$/' test_data
```

The above code is not printing that .How to fix it so that I can use the repetition symbol?
I know the alternative like `awk  '/^....$/' test_data` and `awk  'length ==3 ' test_data`

Comment: What distribution are you using? Which awk?

Comment: $ awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.7     $ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago)

Comment: I'd say `awk '/^.{4}+$/{print}' <<<$'foods\nbaarsz\nfooo'`  to match exactly 4 chars. Also as you mentioned yourself,  `awk 'length($0) == 4' test_data` is compatible with almost all `awk` versions.

Comment: Do `awk --re-interval '/^.{4}$/' test_data`  or `awk --posix '/^.{4}$/' test_data` work?

Comment: Thank you steeldriver. This solved my issue. Upvoted. Thanks again :)

Comment: @steeldriver may as well post that as an answer.

Comment: It helps if both of you explain that GNU Awk 3.1.7 is from 2009, i.e. very old.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [The GNU Awk User's Guide: Feature History](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Feature-History.html), support for regular expression range operators was added in version 3.0 but initially required explicit command line option

New command-line options:

> - New command-line options:
>
>   - The --lint-old option to warn about constructs that are not available in the original Version 7 Unix version of awk (see V7/SVR3.1).
>   - The -m option from BWK awk. (Brian was still at Bell Laboratories at the time.) This was later removed from both his awk and from gawk.
>   - The --re-interval option to provide interval expressions in regexps (see Regexp Operators).
>   - The --traditional option was added as a better name for --compat (see Options).

In `gawk` 4.0,

> Interval expressions became part of default regular expressions

Since you are using `gawk` 3.x, you will need to use

```
awk --re-interval '/^.{4}$/'
```

or

```
awk --posix '/^.{4}$/'
```

or (thanks @StéphaneChazelas) if you want a solution that is portable, use

```
POSIXLY_CORRECT=anything awk '/^.{4}$/'
```

(since `--posix` or `--re-interval` would cause an error in other `awk` implementations).

Comment: Thanks steeldriver, for your time and help. Upvoted and accepted as an answer

Comment: It's better to use `POSIXLY_CORRECT=anything awk '/^.{4}/'` as that makes portable code (a `--posix` or `--re-interval` would cause an error in other `awk` implementations).

Comment: Hi Stéphane Chazelas, when I issued the command , $ POSIXLY_CORRECT=anything awk '/^.{4}/' test_data, it printed all the lines. Then I realized the there is no last dollar after repetitions. Thanks for your inputs. Upvoting your comment and solution. Sorry I misunderstood it in the first place due to omission of the $ after repetition.

Answer (score 20):

EREs (*extended regular expressions* as used by `awk` or `egrep`) initially didn't have `{x,y}`. It was first introduced in BREs (as used by `grep` or `sed`), but with the `\{x,y\}` syntax that didn't break backward portability.

But when it was added to EREs with that `{x,y}` syntax, it did break backward portability as a `foo{2}` RE was matching something different before.

So some implementations chose not to do it. You'll find that `/bin/awk`, `/bin/nawk` and `/bin/egrep` on Solaris still don't honour it (you need to use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep -E`). Same for `awk` and `nawk` on FreeBSD (based on [the `awk` maintained by Brian Kernighan](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk) (the `k` in `awk`)).

[For GNU `awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Operators.html#index-interval-expressions_002c-regexp-operator), until relatively recently (version 4.0), you had to call it with `POSIXLY_CORRECT=anything awk '/^.{4}$/'` for it to honour it. [`mawk` still doesn't honour it](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/original-mawk/issues/25).

Note that that operator is only syntactic sugar. `.{3,5}` can always be written `....?.?` for instance (though of course `{3,5}` is a lot more legible, and the equivalent of `(foo.{5,9}bar){123,456}` would be a lot worse).

Comment: Thanks again Stéphane Chazelas. Sorry, my bad, I was unable to comprehend your answer initially. Thanks a lot and upvoted.

Answer (score 6):

This works as expected with GNU `awk` (gawk):

```
$ printf 'abcd\nabc\nabcde\n' | gawk '/^.{4}$/'
abcd
```

But fails with `mawk` which is closer to POSIX `awk` and, AFAIK, is the default on Ubuntu systems:

```
$ printf 'abcd\nabc\nabcde\n' | mawk '/^.{4}$/'
$ ## prints nothing
```

So, a simple solution would be to use `gawk` instead of `awk`. The `{n}` notation isn't part of the POSIX BRE (basic regular expression) syntax. That's why `grep` also fails here:

```
$ printf 'abcd\nabc\nabcde\n' | grep '^.{4}$'
$
```

However, it is part of ERE (extended regular expressions):

```
$ printf 'abcd\nabc\nabcde\n' | grep -E '^.{4}$'
abcd
```

<del>I don't know which regex flavor is used by `mawk` or POSIX `awk`, but I would guess it's BRE</del>. They use an older version of ERE according to [Stéphane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/354559/22222). In any case, either you are apparently using a version of `awk` that doesn't implement ERE or your input doesn't actually have any lines with exactly 4 characters. This could happen because of whitespace that you don't see or unicode glyphs, for example.

Comment: Hi terdon, I want to print the lines which are 4 characters long. Not the first four characters of a line. For example $ grep -E '^.{4}$' test_data , will work but same is not working with awk

Comment: @CppLearner yes, that's what I'm doing here. What do you mean?

Comment: @CppLearner, @terdon's solution does only print lines which are 4 characters long. But if you're really only interested in line length, you should just use `length($0)` which is more efficient than regexes.

Comment: Hi terdon , steeldriver 's solution is what I was looking for. Thanks for your time. Hi Stephen Kitt , As I mentioned in the problem, I already used the length as alternative,  I was more interested in knowing why the repetition regex {n} is not working from steeldriver's comment I came to know that I need to use the option of --re-interval  or --posix. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @CppLearner then please accept Stéphane's answer since he explains why they don't work.

Comment: Yes I am trying to understand that, and will accept in a minute or two as  continuous edits are happening to Stéphane Chazelas' answer.

Comment: `mawk` is not really closer to POSIX `awk`, and doesn't use BREs. It does use EREs but without the `{x,y}` operator.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas it isn't? `man mawk`  on my Arch claims: "*mawk is a new awk meaning it implements the AWK language as defined in  Aho, Kernighan  and Weinberger, The AWK Programming Language [. . . ] mawk  conforms  to  the POSIX 1003.2 (draft 11.3) definition of the AWK language which contains a few features not described in the AWK book,  and  mawk provides a small number of extensions."* That sounds like not-quite-POSIX-but-close or, at least, closer than GNU awk.

Comment: A POSIX draft from 1992. It doesn't support `{x,y}`, it doesn't support multi-byte characters (so is not POSIX on systems with such charsets). It has a funny input buffering behaviour (not sure that breaks POSIX conformance though) It has fewer extensions over the standard than gawk but is less conformant than gawk.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas huh, OK. I had assumed that fewer extensions == more conformant. Thanks.

Comment: Extensions don't necessarily break compliance if they don't get in the way of the standard syntax. A lot of gawk extensions do get in the way though and so are disabled when POSIXLY_CORRECT is in the environment. For instance, gawk would fail to interpret a POSIX script that does `function gensub() {...}`. There are some extensions that still get in the way even with POSIXLY_CORRECT. For instance `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 awk 'BEGIN{nextfile = 1}'` fails with gawk (and many other awk implementations including mawk (@ThomasDickey's version).