# Clarify grep & regex

Tags: grep, osx, regular-expression

set of words that are 10 characters long and that contain a substring of three consecutive vowels. So far I tried these command.

```
grep -E '^.{10}$'| grep 'a*.e*.i*.o*.u*' words2.txt
grep -E '^.{10}$&a*.e*.i*.o*.u*' words2.txt
```

Input data, extracted via OCR of [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6h4g.jpg):

```
unpernicious
unperspicuous
unpervious
unpious
unpiteous
unpiteously
unpiteousness
unplebeian
unplenteous
unportmanteaued
unportuous
unprecarious
unprecious
unprecocious
unpredacious
unpresumptuous
unpresumptuously
unpretentious
unpretentiously
unpretentiousness
unpromiscuous
unpropitious
unpropitiously
unpropitiousness
unpugnacious
unpunctilious
unquailed
unquailing
unquailingly
unqueen
unqueened
unqueening
unqueenlike
unqueenly
unquiescence
unquiescent
unquiescently
unquiet
unquietable
unquieted
unquieting
unquietly
unquietness
unquietude
unrapacious
unrebellious
unreligious
unreligiously
unreligiousness
unrighteous
unrighteously
unrighteousness
unsacrilegious
Unsagacious
unsalubrious
unsanctimonious
unsanctimoniously
unsanctimoniousness
unsanguineous
unsanguineously
unseditious
unseeable
unseeing
```

Comment: Should it report words like `plateauing` (4 consecutive vowels)?

Comment: Please be more specific in your question's title. That new _"need a help and clarify with grep & regex"_ title is not useful and won't help you get answers or help people with a similar need find this Q&A. The original title (_"Find the set of words that are exactly 10 characters long and that contain a substring of 3 consecutive vowels"_) was a lot better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is (IMHO) better solved with `awk`, but I'll just point out a problem with your command

```
grep -E '^.{10}$'| grep 'a*.e*.i*.o*.u*' words2.txt
```

To filter the contents of the file `word2.txt` through both `grep` invocations, this ought to look like

```
grep -E '^.{10}$' words2.txt | grep 'a*.e*.i*.o*.u*'
```

The second `grep` pattern should be `[auoie]{3}`, which lands us at

```
grep -E '^.{10}$' words2.txt | grep -E '[aouie]{3}'
```

The input to the first `grep` is your file.  The input to the second `grep` is the output of the first `grep`, *not* your file.

Using a POSIX `awk` (like recent versions of GNU `awk`):

```
$ awk 'length == 10 && /[aouei]{3}/' words2.txt
unpervious
unplebeian
unportuous
unprecious
unquailing
unqueening
unquieting
unquietude
```

`mawk`, BSD `awk` and historical pre-POSIX implementations of `awk` don't support `{n}` in regular expressions as [pointed out by Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/354559).

Answer (score 2):

You had the 10 characters right, but to find 3 vowels in a row, look for a group `[AEIOU]`:

```
egrep '^.{10}$' | egrep -i '[AEIOU]{3}'
```

To reject whitepace use this:

```
egrep '^[^ \t]{10}$' | egrep -i '[AEIOu]{3}'
```

Comment: it worked, but some of them has words less than 10 characters :('

Comment: Is there extra whitespace?

Comment: nope, there aren't any whitespaces, but there are characters less than 10, I need characters either  10 or more than 10 that contain a substring of 3 consecutive vowels

Comment: To help further, you are likely going to need to show some sample data in your post.

Comment: Maybe an encryption issue? Do the words with less characters contain any "special" characters like with accents or umlauts?

Comment: here is some sample text - https://jsfiddle.net/cuemxt7a/

Comment: That would be sample text.  But it is not in your post, and it has no words with 10 characters and 3 consecutive vowels.  The desire is some sample text edited into your post that demonstrates your problem.  Then we can try to fix the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: here are the full text https://jsfiddle.net/cuemxt7a/1/

Comment: @Philippos nope letters only

Comment: here are some sample output I got - http://imgur.com/a/6eLCm @StephenRauch

Comment: Pictures are of no value.  No one can copy and paste pictures to test.

Comment: I did an OCR of the image and got `unpervious unplebeian unportuous unprecious unquailing unqueening unquieting unquietude` which seems pretty much what you want. No words with less than 10 chars.

Comment: @Philippos actually there are, for an example, words like 'unpious' just only have  characters, not exactly 10.

Comment: @StephenRauch dr01 edited the answer with the screen shot that i got

Comment: @StephenRauch The OP is putting the input file name at the very end of the command line.

Comment: @MariyamMohammedJalil Actually, I tested with the given word list I OCRed and the script by Stephen and I didn't get "unpious", but only those 10-char-words I listed above! So your file seems to be different, something like trailing CR characters, but we can't see non-printable characters in a screen shot. Use `egrep '\<.{10}\>' wordlist.txt | egrep -i '[AEIOU]{3}'` to make it work even with hidden characters

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 1 word/line, you can do this:

```
sed -nE '/^.{10}$/!d;/[aAeEiIoOuU]{3}/p' words.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With `grep` built with PCRE support:

```
grep -iPx '(?=.*[aeiou]{3}.*).{10}'
```

Or:

```
grep -wiP '(?=\w*[aeiou]{3}\w*)\w{10}'
```

to search for those words when they're not one per line (add `-o` if your `grep` implementation supports it to print the matching words only instead of the whole line they're found in). There *word* means any sequence of *word* characters (letters (in the latin script, without diacritics only, add a `(*UCP)` for letters in any script, though that still won't cover vowels like `é` or `α`), digits and underscore).